# standard Numeric Input

Tags: c++, c

hi 
   i wana know how to use standard numeric input for a user to just enter numbers in the entering field in c or c++? Any one who told me any string or way with if else or switch or ternary operators.

Comment: Huh? What? (filling up the space)

Comment: what do u mean by filling up the space?

Comment: comments have to be >= 15 chars

Answer (score 1):

For C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int myValue;
cin >> myValue;

if (!cin)
{
  // bad or missing input
}
else
{
  // party on with the int
}
```

Also works with other builtin numeric types.  If you want to then use the input as a `string`:

```
#include <sstream>

ostringstream intStream;
intStream << myValue;
string intString(intStream.str());
```

If you wanted to do this in C, you would use [scanf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9y6s16x1.aspx).  Lots of examples online, such as this.  It's easy to introduce horrible buffer overflow bugs when capturing input data in an array like the below.  If you have the choice, I would use C++.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char str [80];
  int i;

  printf ("Enter your family name: ");
  scanf ("%s",str);  
  printf ("Enter your age: ");
  scanf ("%d",&i);
  printf ("Mr. %s , %d years old.\n",str,i);
  printf ("Enter a hexadecimal number: ");
  scanf ("%x",&i);
  printf ("You have entered %#x (%d).\n",i,i);

  return 0;
}
```

Docs on different input format specifiers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwwtf9ch.aspx).

Comment: cin>> myvalue; what is this line for

Comment: It reads the requested type from the standard input stream.  Is that why this is downvoted?

Comment: @James - I'd been meaning to ask a question about that.  Thanks for the clarification.  Those `rdstate` flags seem a bit confusing to me.

Comment: @Steve:  I apologize for my comment; I was in fact wrong (apparently I was confused too...).  I answered your question on the subject and realized I was totally wrong.  `.fail()` would work fine too.

Comment: @James - :-) I am just glad it's not just me that gets this all mixed up evey time I need to use it.  Thanks also for putting all the info in one place in that answer.  btw MSDN has `basic_ios` with `explicit operator bool`, is that an MS extension?

Comment: C++0x adds support for explicit conversion operators; these fix the problem that causes us to have to use safe-bool in C++03.  That said, it's odd that MSDN lists that.  Visual C++ 2010 does not support explicit conversion operators.

Comment: Interesting.  C++0x in VC++ is only partly done, perhaps this was an easy win.  I see now that this is new in VS2010 (no dropdown for 'other versions').

Comment: See post edit.  Lots more examples online, just Google for 'scanf example'.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <iostream>

 int main()
 {
   std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
   int i = 0;
   while (std::cin >> i) {
            // process
 }
```

This will cause the while loop to exit either when you hit end-of-file, or when you enter a bad integer.